# Move kubernetes (kubespray) nodes to another IP range

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I installed a kubernetes cluster by using kuberspray on my internal network, 192.168.0.0/24.
Now I need more nodes and these nodes will be located on other networks.
So I will set up a VPN between the current nodes and the new nodes.

The problem is that I cannot find any information specifically related to kubespray on how to change the internal IPs of the nodes in order to "move them on the VPN".
I think after moving the nodes on the VPN, then it's just a matter of installing the new nodes in the cluster and I'm set.

So: Using kubespray (or manually if not possible via kubespray directly) how can I change the internal IPs of the nodes in order to move them on the VPN?

Comment: Which version of Kubespray are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Kubespray supports `kubeadm` for cluster creation since v2.3 and deprecated non-kubeadm deployment starting from v2.8.
I assume that you can use `kubeadm` with your Kubespray installation. 
I see two ways to achieve your goal. Both from Kubernetes side:

1. By using `ifconfig` command:

   - run `kubeadm reset` on the node you want to reconfig
   - run `ifconfig <network interface> <IP address>`
   - run `kubeadm join` in order to add the node again with the new IP
2. By editing the `kubelet.conf` file:

   - run `systemctl status kubelet` to find out the location of your `kubelet.conf` (usually `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`)
   - edit it by adding `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--node-ip=<IP_ADDRESS>`
   - run `systemctl daemon-reload`
   - run `systemctl restart kubelet`

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: no unfortunately not. If I edit `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env` (the equivalent of the conf file you mention) and set `--node-ip` on a worker node then reload and restart kubelet nothing happens when I `kubectl get nodes -o wide`. I also tried a variation of https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755 to no avail.